# Ionic Angular '[console.error]: "ERROR" {}' without any explanation / log

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

[image]

Hello, I am having errors in my Ionic App.

I'm running

```
ionic cordova run android --livereload --consolelogs --serverlogs
```

with a physical phone.

As you can see I'm able to see console.logs, but there must be an error that is creating the

```
[console.error]: "ERROR" {}
```

But it doesn't explain anything! There is no error logs or stack trace error. I don't have any console.error in my code, so it must be an unhandled error somewhere...

Has anybody experienced something like this? I don't know what to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered chrome://inspect/#devices.

Using inspect, it displays perfectly the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on iOS while running an Ionic App through Xcode.

In this case it's possible to use safari to inspect the webview and show javascript errors not shown with `--consolelogs`.

To open javascript console you have to:

- enable "Web inspector" inside Safari advanced settings on Iphone
- connect Iphone through USB (if it's not connected yet)
- open safari on Mac and navigate `Develop` > `Your Iphone name` > `localhost`